# How to use a html form to send data to javascript to be saved as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to use html and javascript (strictly no php) to have a html data entry form to pass data to js to be saved as a variable. Any help would be appreciated :)

This is what a have so far:

```
        <form id="myform"> //form name
            What is your name: <input type='text' name='name'> //name input
            <a href="javascript: formCatch(name)">Go</a> // running some kind of function?
        </form>
```

and then the js side

```
var name = 'test';   

function formCatch() { //declare function 'formCatch'
        name = document.forms["myform"].submit();  // set the name variable as the contents from the form
        alert('hello, ' + name); // alert to test the output
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the second line of the function is incorrect. 
What I'm looking for in that function is for the data entered into the form on the html page to be saved as the name variable.

Comment: You might be interested in jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's what you're looking for:

```
<script>
    var name = 'test';   

    function formCatch() {
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
        name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        alert('hello, ' + name);
    }
</script>

<form id="myform">
    What is your name: <input id="name" type='text' name='name'>
    <a href="javascript:formCatch();">Go</a>
</form>
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riless/cq9kyjr3/)

Comment: to submit the form, that's what @user3932399 wants I think.

Answer (score 1):

### (EDITED)

**HTML :**

```
What is your name: <input type='text' id='name'/> 
            <a onclick="formCatch();" href="#">Go</a>
```

**JS :**

```
function formCatch() { 
        name = getElementById("name").value;
        alert('hello, ' + name);
    }
```

Comment: Replacing the old function with this one doesn't seem to be working.
Do i still have to run that function?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to submit your form, just access the value of your name.

```
name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
```